# Why is the geodesic curvature of a great circle equal to zero on a sphere? Is the curvature of a small circle not equal to zero?

Tags: differential-geometry

Why is the geodesic curvature of a great circle equal to zero on a sphere? Is the curvature of a small circle not equal to zero?

A great circle is a circle, and a small circle is a circle. Isn't the curvature of a circle equal to the reciprocal of its radius?

Answer (score 6):

Well yes, both your claims are right.

The thing is that those are not the same circles. The great circle on the sphere is not the same as any circle on $\mathbb{R}^n$. You call them both "circles" but they are curves on different manifolds.

Geodesic curvature measures how far a certain curve is from being a geodesic, and that is also specific to the manifold that you're working on. A great circle on the sphere, with the round metric, is a geodesic, so its geodesic curvature is $0$ and your first paragraph is right.

When you claim that the geodesic curvature of a circle is the reciprocal of its radius, you're also right... for circles on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Here you're considering the geodesic curvature of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the Euclidean metric, where geodesics are straight lines.

Comment: Isn't it more accurate to say $\mathbb{R}^n$ when the geometry is euclidean?  Other geometries have other geodesics.

Comment: @QthePlatypus Of course, you're absolutely right. I meant it implicitly but that'll make it more clear and it's an important idea. I'll edit accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be asking (and I'm certainly answering) about "curvature" and "geodesic curvature" in the *standard* meanings of those terms, *not* in the context of your alternative geometry (explored in your other questions) where all circles great and small are considered "straight".

The general theory of geodesic curvature can get complicated, and web searches can drop you right into a terminological and notational wilderness; I'll try to make this answer as elementary and self-contained as possible. Restricting attention to circular paths and spherical surfaces will greatly simplify discussion.

(BTW: You don't have to take my word for this stuff. The first two or three pages of [this write-up (PDF)](https://www.math.uh.edu/~minru/Riemann09/four1.pdf), for instance, is relatively straightforward —though a bit jargon-y at the beginning— in describing the same concepts.)

---

Consider a path just doing its pathy thing in space. Conveniently parameterizing by arc-length $s$, we'll denote the path's position vector by $\alpha(s)$ (although I'll often remove the $s$ to reduce notational clutter). Arc-length parameterization can generally be messy (circles are nicer, as I'll explain below), but part of the convenience is that

- $\alpha'(s)$ (or, just $\alpha'$) is naturally the unit direction vector tangent to the path, providing a sense of *forward* (and *backward*).
- $\alpha''(s)$ (or, just $\alpha''$), the path's acceleration vector, represents the path's tendency to veer away from forward. This, quite reasonably, is the notion we call ''curvature'', whose value ($\kappa$) we define as the length of $\alpha''$.

$$\kappa(s) := |\alpha''(s)| \qquad\left(\;\kappa := |\alpha''|\;\right) \tag{1}$$

---

As an aside, let's confirm that the formulas work as expected. Consider an origin-centered circle of radius $r$ in the $xy$-plane. The arc-length parameterization of the path is
$$\alpha(s) = \left(r \cos\frac{s}{r}, r\sin\frac{s}{r}, 0\right) \tag{2}$$
(When $r=1$, this is the standard parameterization of the unit circle.) The direction vector is 
$$\alpha'(s) = \left(-\sin\frac{s}{r}, \cos\frac{s}{r}, 0\right) \tag{3}$$
which obviously(?) has unit length, is tangent to the path since $\alpha\cdot\alpha' = 0$. The acceleration vector is
$$\alpha''(s) = \left(-\frac{1}{r}\cos\frac{s}{r},-\frac{1}{r}\sin\frac{s}{r}, 0\right) \quad\to\quad |\alpha''| = \sqrt{\frac{1}{r^2}\cos^2\frac{s}{r}+\frac{1}{r^2}\sin^2\frac{s}{r}} = \frac{1}{r} \tag{4}$$
whose length is the reciprocal of the circle's radius, exactly matching our expectation about a circle's curvature, as claimed.

---

That analysis is all well and good, but it only applies to paths "in the wild". For a path trapped —that is, *embedded*— in a surface, it makes sense to adapt the notion of path curvature to be somehow *relative* to that surface. After all, the surface introduces a sense of *upward* (perpendicular to itself), and it therefore effectively "absorbs" the up/down component of the path's non-forward tendencies. For a path in a surface, "curvature" measures its tendency to veer away from forward *and upward*.

To formalize this, let's (re)define:

- $f(s) := \alpha'(s)$ (or, $f := \alpha'$), the path's unit direction vector, which provides the path's sense of *forward*.
- $u(s)$ (or, just $u$), the unit normal vector to the surface, which provides the surface's sense of *upward*.
  On an origin-centered, radius-$r$ sphere, this is simply $(x,y,z)/\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} = \frac{1}{r}(x,y,z)$; so, for points on path $\alpha$ on such a sphere, we have $u = \frac{1}{r}\alpha$.
- $\ell(s) := u(s)\times f(s)$ (or, $\ell:= u\times f$), yet another unit vector, this one perpendicular to the upward-forward plane, providing a sense of *leftward* drift away from that plane.
  For (*deep breath*) an arc-length-parameterized path on an origin-centered, radius-$r$ sphere, we substitute-in from the above items to get: $\ell = \frac{1}{r} \alpha\times\alpha'$.

(You may recall my metaphor of the ant with the sticks. Those sticks represent these vectors.)

When one has three vectors that span space, one's inclination is to express arbitrary vectors as combinations of them. In particular, we do that with the path's acceleration vector:

$$\alpha'' = a f + b u + c \ell \tag{5}$$

where $a$, $b$, $c$ (like everything else) depend upon $s$. The acceleration vector is naturally perpendicular to direction, so we always have $a=0$. Coefficients $b$ and $c$ are usually written as $\kappa_n$ and $\kappa_g$, so that we have

$$\alpha'' = \kappa_n u + \kappa_g \ell \tag{6}$$

As $\ell$ is directed "leftward" ---that is, neither *forward* nor *upward*--- the coefficient $\kappa_g$ captures the path's tendency (relative to the surface's own tendency) to veer *sideways*. This is the value we dub "geodesic curvature". (Likewise, $\kappa_n$ is "normal curvature" ... with "normal" as in "normal vector", not "normal" as in "ordinary"!)

Because $f$, $u$, $\ell$ are mutually-orthogonal unit vectors, we can readily isolate $\kappa_g$ as follows:

$$\alpha'' \cdot \ell = \kappa_n\;u\cdot\ell + \kappa_g\;\ell\cdot\ell = \kappa_g \qquad\to\qquad \kappa_g = \frac{1}{r}\left(\alpha \times \alpha' \right)\cdot\alpha'' \tag{7}$$

(the latter formulation applying specifically to our paths on the origin-centered, radius-$r$ sphere).

---

With that background, we can (finally) get to your main question.

Let's consider a circular path at latitude $\lambda$ on an origin-centered, radius-$r$ sphere. This circle has radius $r\cos\lambda$ and sits level at distance $r\sin\lambda$ from the $xy$-plane; we can therefore express its arc-length-parameterized position vector by
$$\alpha_\lambda(s) = \left(r\cos\lambda \cos\frac{s}{r\cos\lambda}, r\cos\lambda \sin\frac{s}{r\cos\lambda}, r\sin\lambda\right) \tag{8}$$
Then we have
$$\begin{align}
\alpha_\lambda^\prime &= \left(-\sin\frac{s}{r\cos\lambda},\cos\frac{s}{r\cos\lambda}, 0 \right) \tag{9}\\[4pt]
\alpha_\lambda^{\prime\prime} &=  \left(-\frac{1}{r\cos\lambda}\cos\frac{s}{r\cos\lambda},-\frac{1}{r\cos\lambda}\sin\frac{s}{r\cos\lambda}, 0 \right) \tag{10}
\end{align}$$
which, by $(7)$, gives

> $$\kappa_g = \frac{1}{r}\tan\lambda \tag{$\star$}$$
>   The *geodesic curvature* for a latitude-circle on the sphere is zero *only* at latitude $\lambda=0$ ... that is, when the path is the equator; since any great circle can be rotated into equatorial position, and any non-great circle *can't*, we have that *all great circles have geodesic curvature curvature zero*, and *all non-great circles have non-zero geodesic curvature*.

(The non-great latitude-circle's curvature increases as latitude increases, until we achieve (as we might expect) *infinite* curvature for the North Pole's point-circle at latitude $90^\circ$.)

Comment: The rectifying plane is perpendicular to the osculating plane and the normal plane.
A new definition of geodesic curvature: curve (C) on surface S, whose absolute value of geodesic curvature at point P equals the curvature of the orthographic projection curve (C*) on the rectifying plane Π of point P.
Note that what I'm talking about here is the orthographic projection on the rectifying plane.

Comment: The problem with the old definition is that when determining the geodesic curvature of a spherical curve, it excludes the influence of the spherical surface on a great circle, but does not exclude the influence of the spherical surface on a small circle (because the sphere is a curved surface). The spherical effect is excluded in the new definition. So the new definition is more scientific.

Comment: Under the new definition, the geodesic curvature of the small circles and the great circles on the sphere is equal to zero. Because their projections on rectifying planes are straight lines. So, in the new definition, the sphere has parallel lines. For example, the latitude line is parallel to the equatorial line.Under the new definition, three points determine a straight line, and there are countless straight lines over two points.
In sphere, can the geodesic curvature of a small circle be defined by orthographic projection in rectifying plane?

Comment: @E.wei: I answered the question in the context of the standard definition of curvature. If you wanted something else, you should've said so in the question.

Comment: I know you're talking about standard answers.

Answer (score 0):

The rectifying plane is perpendicular to the osculating plane and the normal plane.

[image]

A new definition of geodesic curvature: curve $(C)$ on surface $S$, whose absolute value of geodesic curvature at point $P$ equals the curvature of the orthographic projection curve $(C*)$ on the rectifying plane $Π$ of point $P$.

[image]

Note that what I'm talking about here is the orthographic projection on the rectifying plane.

The problem with the old definition is that when determining the geodesic curvature of a spherical curve, it excludes the influence of the spherical surface on a great circle, but does not exclude the influence of the spherical surface on a small circle (because the sphere is a curved surface). The spherical effect is excluded in the new definition. So the new definition is more scientific.

Under the new definition, the geodesic curvature of the small circles and the great circles on the sphere is equal to zero. Because their projections on rectifying planes are straight lines. So, in the new definition, the sphere has parallel lines. For example, the latitude line is parallel to the equatorial line.Under the new definition, three points determine a straight line, and there are countless straight lines over two points.

In sphere, can the geodesic curvature of a small circle be defined by orthographic projection in rectifying plane?

---

It should be noted that in the plane, the tangent curvature of point P on the curve is equal to zero, but the curvature of the curve at point P is not necessarily equal to zero. On the sphere, the geodesic curvature of the curve at osculating circle at P point is equal to zero (the geodesic curvature of any circle is equal to zero), but the geodesic curvature of the curve at P point is not necessarily equal to zero. We must overcome our habitual thinking.

---

**A Method for Calculating Geodetic Curvature of Spherical Curves**

The tangent of a curve on a plane is a straight line. Because the geodesic curvature of the circle on the sphere is zero, the tangent of the curve on the sphere is osculating circle, that is to say, the tangent of a point on the spherical curve is osculating circle of the curve at that point. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jq4MH.jpg)

Since the geodesic curvature of any circle is zero, the angle between the planes of any two circles is the spherical angle. That is, the sides of the spherical angle can also be small arcs.

[image]

As shown in the figure, there is a red curve $C$ on the sphere. There are two points on the curve $C$. $M$ and $N$. The green circle is the tangent of the curve $C$ at the $N$ point and the osculating circle of the curve $C$ at the $N$ point. The yellow circle is the tangent of the curve $C$ at the $M$ point and the osculating circle of the curve $C$ at the $M$ point. Let the length of the curve $C$ between $M$ and $N$ be $L$, and let the angle between the green circle and the yellow circle be $\alpha$. The average geodesic curvature is

Average geodesic curvature of $MN = α/L$

When $N$ point approaches $M$ point along curve $C$, the limit of average geodesic curvature of $MN$ is called geodesic curvature of curve $C$ at $M$ point.

Therefore, although the geodesic curvature of any circle on the sphere is equal to zero, the geodesic curvature of the curve on the sphere is not necessarily zero.

Comment: @Blue I think about a definition. Under my definition, the curvature of a small circle equals zero. Of course, the curvature of a great circle equals zero.

Comment: As I've said all along, you're free to define curvature however you like; whether your definition is "more scientific" than the standard definition is a matter of opinion, so I won't speak to that. Here's something to ask yourself, however: If small circles have zero "E.wei-curvature", then does *any* path on the sphere have non-zero E.wei-curvature?

Comment: @Blue  You may not come up with your concept of curvature, but Gauss will come up with it, and I will come up with it.
You should note that there are not only circles on the sphere, but also other paths on the sphere. The geodesic curvature of these paths is certainly not all zero, of course, the geodesic curvature of some of their points is zero.

Comment: There's that attitude again. (Have you ever considered showing some *gratitude* to people who are trying to help you?) Anyway, you can *claim* that the E.wei-curvature (calling it "geodesic curvature" is inappropriate, since that term is already defined) of non-circle curves is "certainly not all zero", but until you show how to *calculate* that curvature, your claim is empty. (I'll note that, typically, one expects curvature to match the limit of approximating circles; if all circles have E.wei-curvature zero, then all these limits are zero, too. But maybe that doesn't matter.)

Comment: @Blue First of all, thank you for your query. You are a little confused. We usually think of curves as composed of many small segments, and the curvature of these small segments is zero, but the curvature of the curve is not zero. Why?

Comment: I'm not confused, thanks. As for how "we" usually think of curves, with particular regard to curvature matching the limit of circular curvatures as I described above, I invite you to read about [osculating circles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osculating_circle#Properties): "For a curve $C$ [...], the osculating circle [at a point $P$, with curvature matching the curvature at $P$] may be obtained by a limiting procedure: it is the limit of the circles passing through three distinct points on $C$ as these points approach $P$." Anyway ... I'm done here (again). Good luck to you.

Comment: @Blue  You still don't understand my idea. On the plane, the tangent curvature of point P on the curve is equal to zero, but the curvature of the curve at point P is not necessarily equal to zero. On the sphere, the geodesic curvature of the curve at osculating circle at point P is equal to zero, but the geodesic curvature of the curve at point P is not necessarily equal to zero. You are not familiar with new geometry, and your habits make you prone to errors.

Comment: @E.wei You refuse to try to understand the things you're trying to redefine. This causes you some problems. Firstly, your definition of curvature of a curve in a surface doesn't depend at all on the surface you're embedding into. Either that, or you haven't clearly communicated your idea. It appears to be defined to be the curvature in the plane of the projection of the curve along the normal onto the rectifying plane. Nowhere does this mention the surface. More problematically, by projecting along the normal you kill the curvature, so every curve has zero curvature by this definition.

Comment: Also definitions aren't "scientific" or not, they're useful or not. Let us know when you prove something interesting with this definition. For reference, the standard definitions of curvature give us beautiful theorems like [Gauss-Bonnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss–Bonnet_theorem).

Comment: @jgon You should note that the geodesic curvature of a great circle is also projected onto the rectifying plane. In addition, the GB theorem is not necessarily valid under the new definition.

Comment: @jgon The answer adds the content of geodesic curvature calculation of spherical general curve. I hope it will be helpful for you to understand my thoughts.

Comment: @Blue The answer adds the content of geodesic curvature calculation of spherical general curve. I hope it will be helpful for you to understand my thoughts.